# Postgresql database location for maven build tests

Tags: maven

I have big maven project. So I run mvn clean install. But I get errors on tests. The sql connection exception. I have sql file with database for Postgresql. Should I have create  database (with user and password) on localhost? So how do junit tests run? Do they need server with database on localhost?
This xml for connection database:

```
        <bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/lion" />
            <property name="user" value="osm" />
            <property name="password" value="101918" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
            <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
            <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
            <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="100" />
        </bean>
```

Comment: I wrote a plugin you might be interested in: https://github.com/adrianboimvaser/postgresql-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Yes, apparently you have a project with Spring integration tests connecting to real PostgreSQL database. Most likely other developers have such a database installed so it works for them. Not perfect but sometimes necessary.

That being said yes, you need to isntall PostgreSQL, create `lion` database and all needed tables. Moreover database user name and password are apparently hard-coded in your configuration (should they be posted here?), so you must either create the same user in your PostgreSQL server or (better) externalize `jdbcUrl`, `username` and `password`.

Finally consider incorporating [flyway](/questions/tagged/flyway), brilliant little library that will create your database tables if you start an application on empty schema.

Comment: I have been given PostgreSQL database dump. Can I create database from it?

Comment: @Thomasz How would you test a PostgreSQL based Java application. Which plugins would you use to populate a test database?Or can this all be done using the sql-maven-plugin and a sql dump?